# No exact amount estimate price for UberX

Tags: python, uber-api

Currently within the app, requesting a UberX instantly give you a exact quote price but in the Python API, I couldn't find it. I can only find the range of the cost. Where is the exact quote at?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use "[POST /v1.2/requests/estimate](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-estimate-post)"

Example Request

```
curl -X POST \
 -H 'Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>' \
 -H 'Accept-Language: en_US' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -d '{
   "start_latitude": 37.7752278,
   "start_longitude": -122.4197513,
   "end_latitude": 37.7773228,
   "end_longitude": -122.4272052
 }' "https://api.uber.com/v1.2/requests/estimate"
```

I suggest you use "product_id" as well - to get the price for the product you need. Otherwise, if none is provided, it will default to the cheapest product for the given location.

You will get the response like:

```
{
"fare": {
"value": 5.73,
"fare_id": "d30e732b8bba22c9cdc10513ee86380087cb4a6f89e37ad21ba2a39f3a1ba960",
"expires_at": 1476953293,
"display": "$5.73",
"currency_code": "USD",
"breakdown": [
 {
   "type": "promotion",
   "value": -2.00,
   "name": "Promotion"
 },
 {
   "type": "base_fare",
   "notice": "Fares are slightly higher due to increased demand",
   "value": 7.73,
   "name": "Base Fare"
 }
 ]
},
"trip": {
"distance_unit": "mile",
"duration_estimate": 540,
"distance_estimate": 2.39
},
"pickup_estimate": 2
}
```

Related to Pyton SDK - Please check: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/python. You need to authenticate your user, and then get a product you want to use, and then get upfront fare (if product support this: upfront_fare_enabled field set to true). And after that you can book a ride. Code how to do it is in doc link I have sent as well:

```
# Get products for a location
response = client.get_products(37.77, -122.41)
products = response.json.get('products')

product_id = products[0].get('product_id')

# Get upfront fare and start/end locations
estimate = client.estimate_ride(
product_id=product_id,
start_latitude=37.77,
start_longitude=-122.41,
end_latitude=37.79,
end_longitude=-122.41,
seat_count=2
)
fare = estimate.json.get('fare')

# Request a ride with upfront fare and start/end locations
response = client.request_ride(
product_id=product_id,
start_latitude=37.77,
start_longitude=-122.41,
end_latitude=37.79,
end_longitude=-122.41,
seat_count=2,
fare_id=fare['fare_id']
)

request = response.json
request_id = request.get('request_id')

# Request ride details using `request_id`
response = client.get_ride_details(request_id)
ride = response.json

# Cancel a ride
response = client.cancel_ride(request_id)
ride = response.json
```

Comment: Thanks, but how exactly should I implement this? Do I just dump your code into the parenthesis of client.get_price_estimates()?

Comment: Okay, I've been trying this for one full day now and there is a new problem. I wasn't able to authenticate. When I click on the auth_url generated, it came up with an error that says THE BASE REDIRECT URI DOES NOT MATCH THE REQUESTED REDIRECT.

Comment: The error you get is self descriptive - you need to verify is it redirect URL you used in your code the same as redirect URL on your application dashboard. Please read: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/api/python#authorize-a-rider-for-your-application